# Parsing online dictionary results using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse online dictionary results using Jsoup, of which I have a basic understanding. I posted the [HTML I'm trying to parse](http://paste2.org/p/1761539). I'm trying to grab the strings "baseball" and "beisebol", but I'm lacking a clean way of doing this.

Comment: the clean way is simple: don't parse html! Are you allowed to use the dict in your app? is there no other way to access the data (XML, JSON...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult, because neither the words have unique identifier in source code.

But I would do it like that:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://myurl.com").get();
String original = doc.select("td[width=140]").get(1).toString() //get td element which has width of 140 and get the second one
String translated = doc.select("td[align=left]").get(1).toString()//get td element which has align left and get the second one
```

**Note:** When accessing data by scraping, a small change in website design/source code could brake your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with [estivate](https://github.com/btheu/estivate/) (which is a Java DOM Parser with Annotations compatible with JSoup)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://myurl.com").get();

EstivateMapper mapper = new EstivateMapper();

Result result = mapper.map(doc, Result.class);
```

with the defintion of Result class as follow :

```
public class Result {

    @Text(select = "td[width=140]", index=1)
    public String original;

    @Text(select = "td[align=left]", index=1)
    public String translated;

}
```